# How to evaluate $ \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty } \sqrt[x]{a^x+b^x} = ? $

Tags: calculus

If a>0 and b>0, 
$ \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty } \sqrt[x]{a^x+b^x} = ? $

What I was trying to do:
Suppose a>b. Then, for sufficiently large values of x, $ a^x >> b^x $; so $\sqrt[x]{a^x+b^x} \rightarrow \sqrt[x]{a^x} \rightarrow a $ when $x \rightarrow +\infty$.

Is that idea correct? How can I formalize it?

Comment: $a>b \implies a < \sqrt[x]{a^x+b^x} = a\sqrt[x]{1+(b/a)^x} < a\sqrt[x]{2}$. You can take it from here?:)

Comment: Squeeze theorem. Amazing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume $a>b$
$$a^x\leq a^x+b^x\leq 2a^x$$

$$(a^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\leq (a^x+b^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\leq (2a^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

$$a\leq (a^x+b^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\leq 2^{\frac{1}{x}}a$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint : If $a>b$, consider $a^x+b^x=a^x(1+(\frac{b}{a})^x)$ and use the fact that
        the expression in paranthesis tends to $1$.

Answer (score -2):

You can go this way. Assuming $b<a$

> $$ (a^x+b^x)^{1/x} = a \,e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+(b/a)^x) }= a \,e^{\frac{1}{x}((b/a)^x-(b/a)^{2x}/2+\dots ) }\longrightarrow _{x\to \infty } a .$$

I think you can finish it!

**Note:** You need the following power series

> $$ \ln(1+t) = t-\frac{t^2}{2}+ \frac{t^3}{3}-\dots\,.  $$